# Question about Bearings and Trig

Tags: trigonometry

A plane travelled for 600 km from airport A, on a bearing of 210°, before changing direction and travelling a further 250 km on a bearing of 300° to land at airport B.

Calculate the three-figure bearing of airport B from airport A.

Hi, this is a topic about bearings and trigonometry.

I would like some assistance, this is the working I have so far:
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roybU.png)

Thanks

Comment: What is a three-figure bearing?

Comment: A bearing that has three figures, eg. 057 degrees, 256 degrees, 001 degrees etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, it might be helpful to refer to a diagram, as shown below:

[image: Bearing Diagram - Anitej Palur]

Since the plane travelled from airport A on a bearing of $210$°, the angle formed by the line taken by the plane and the first South line is $210 \text {°} - 180 \text {°} = 30$°.

Likewise, after changing direction, since the plane travelled on a bearing of $300$° to airport B, the angle formed by the line taken by the plane and the second West line is $300 \text {°} - 270 \text {°} = 30$°.

Let us now calculate the angle formed between the first line taken by the plane (from A) and the second line (to B).

Notice the relationship between angle $q$ and our calculated angle $30$°. Since both North lines are parallel to each other, the first line taken by the plane forms a [transversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(geometry)). Therefore, angle $q$ and our calculated angle are [alternate angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(geometry)#Alternate_angles). Thus, angle $q = 30$°.

Let us now find angle $p$. Since angle $p$ and our second calculated angle are [complementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Combining_angle_pairs), angle $p = 90 \text {°} - 30 \text {°} = 60$°.

Thus, the angle formed between the first and second line taken by the plane is $90$° i.e. a right-angle triangle is formed.

We can now use trigonometry to calculate angle $\theta$. Since angle $p + q$ forms a right-angle, the distance $250$ kilometres represents the opposite and the distance $600$ kilometres represents the adjacent. Therefore, we can make use of the tangent formula to calculate angle $\theta$, as follows:

> $$tan(\theta) = \frac {\text {opposite}} {\text {adjacent}}$$
>  $$tan(\theta) = \frac {\text {250 km}} {\text {600 km}}$$
>  $$tan(\theta) = \frac {\text {5}} {\text {12}}$$
>  $$\theta = tan^{-1} \left(\frac {\text {5}} {\text {12}}\right)$$
>  $$\therefore \theta = 22.6 \text {°}$$

Thus, the three-figure bearing of airport B from airport A is simply the sum of angle $\theta$ and the first bearing of $210$°, as follows:

> $$22.6 \text {°} + 210 \text {°} = 232.6 \text {°}$$

I hope that helps!

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, thanks for the effort you put onto it

Comment: @Evan My pleasure. :)

Comment: Sorry, but how do we know that p and q are complementary?

Comment: @Evan Angles $p$ and $q$ are complementary since $p = 60$° and $q = 30$°. Note that angle $p$ and our calculated angle $30$° are also complementary.

Comment: Yes but how did we know in the first place that they would add to 90

Comment: @Evan We did not know. It was only after we had found angles $p$ and $q$ did we find that a right-angle was formed. If you are referring to angle $p$ and the calculated $30$°, the angle formed between the North line and the perpendicular West line is complementary (90°). Angle $p$ was not calculated using angle $q$; it was by knowing that the angle formed between the West and North lines was 90°. Another way to calculate angle $p$ is by subtracting 300° (the bearing) from 360°, giving $p = 60$°.

Comment: OHHH SORRY I COMPLETELY IGNORED THE WEST TO NORTH QUADRANT OF THE COMPASS. THANK YOU

Comment: No worries at all. xD